# Laravel: How to implement if statement within {{ }}

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having to pass search filters in links in my laravel app on various occasions. The following statement was working fine in laravel 4, but now I'm converting it to laravel 8 and its giving me error now.

```
{{ link_to_route('workprocess.edit', 'Edit Work Process', array($workprocess->id, json_encode($searchFilters)), array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-warning')) }}
```

***Error***

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: workprocess.edit] [URI: workprocess/edit/{workprocess}/{search?}]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\compliance.local\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

***Reason***
$searchFilters is empty sometimes since the same template is being used for searching as well. `$searchFilters = array('fromdate' => '', 'todate' => '', 'name' => '', 'type' => '');`

I want to put an if statement inside {{ }} for `json_encode($searchFilters)` so that I don't have to write code for two links as there are quite a few other such occurances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an if statement using shorthand for example:

```
{{ $var === "hello" ? "Hi" : "Goodbye" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution;

Where $searchFilters is set:

```
if (empty($searchfilters)) {
    $searchfilters = 1;
};
```

and add a ternary inside `json_encode` method:

`json_encode(empty($searchFilters) != 1 ? $searchFilters : '');`

Comment: doesn't work. Actually, I've observed that json_encode() isn't rendering in blade for unknown reasons.

Comment: `dd(json_encode(' '))` and check what happens, it should throw you back `" "`.